# Invalid anonymous type member declarator error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm doing exactly as described in samples and stackoverflow answers and... but I get the error:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

for this part: `db.Products = p, db.ProductDetails = d`

Here is the code:

```
using(  DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext()){
      var products = db.Products.GroupJoin(db.ProductDetails,
      p => p.ID,
      d => d.ProductID,
      (p, d) => new { db.Products = p, db.ProductDetails = d});
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

and when I do this:

```
using(  DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext()){
      var products = Products.GroupJoin(ProductDetails,
      p => p.ID,
      d => d.ProductID,
      (p, d) => new { Products = p, ProductDetails = d});
}
```

I get these errors:

> The name 'Products' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'ProductDetails' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what samples you're copying, but try this:

```
using(  DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext()){
      var products = db.Products.GroupJoin(db.ProductDetails,
      p => p.ID,
      d => d.ProductID,
      (p, d) => new { Products = p, ProductDetails = d});
}
```

I.e. remove the `db.` from the the anonymous type declaration.

Comment: But when I remove db then everything gets messy and I receive error for everything. how should I write my code to be able to remove db. ?

Comment: and these are mot samples these are my real codes but I have done as shown in the samples

Comment: I can't diagnose "everything gets messy and I receive error for everything". Perhaps you should edit your question to add a description of what you're trying to do, and all the relevant code, and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Ok, edited my answer. I didn't mean remove `db.` from everywhere. See edit.